# Open url like an <a> tag in a Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Just to explain my specific use for it; I made a really simple bookmarklet to open the equalivalent `explainxkcd` page from any `xkcd` comic. It looks like this:

```
javascript:a=new URL(location);a.host==="xkcd.com"&&(a.host="explain"+a.host,open(a))
```

unminified:

```
let url = new URL(location);
if (url.host === "xkcd.com") {
    url.host = "explain" + url.host;
    open(url) # I want this to open "dynamically" like an <a> tag instead
}
```

By open like an `<a>` tag, I mean replace the current tab(`_self`) if the ctrl key isn't held, otherwise open in a new tab(`_blank`) if ctrl is held.
Approaches I've thought of:

- Check `event.ctrlKey` and use that to pass in "_self" or "_blank", but unfortunately, it's not in an event...
- Add a link to the page programatically and then click it. This just feels really hacky.
- Add a `keydown` and `keyup` event and track whether the ctrl key is down, but that doesn't work in a bookmarklet.

Is there some bookmarklet only way to do this, or some method I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Since it's impossible to determine whether the `Ctrl` key is pressed or change behavior based upon it, there is no avoiding other, less ideal solutions.

An example:

```
javascript:void%20function(){if(%22xkcd.com%22===location.host){var%20o=%22https://explain%22+location.host.toString()+location.pathname.toString(),n=confirm(o+%22%20to%20be%20openend%20in%20new%20tab%22);n%3Fwindow.open(o,%22_blank%22):window.location.replace(o)}}();
```

- Trigger a prompt
- Cancel/Escape: current window/tab
- Ok/Enter/Space: new tab

Your 'flow' would become: click on the bookmark, immediately followed by escape or enter based on whether it should open in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I outlined, I *can't* check whether the ctrl key is pressed in a bookmarklet with any of the traditional methods I know. If you know of a way, I'd love if you could show me the implementation.

Comment: @DavidArchibald Unfortunately you're correct. It's not possible to check modifier keys without reading a triggering event.